# A strange bug in discord.py music bot

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, discord.py, python-re

I'm making a discord.py bot that can play music. When I run it on my local machine sometimes everything works just fine but sometimes when I try running it with a playlist, it just cant find songs in the playlist.

Here is the play command:

```
@commands.command(name='play',aliases=["p","sing"])
async def _play(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, song1: str):
    """Plays a song.
    If there are songs in the queue, this will be queued until the
    other songs finished playing.
    This command automatically searches from various sites if no URL is provided.
    A list of these sites can be found here: https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html
    """

    if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
        await ctx.invoke(self._join)
    x = False
    if "playlist?" not in song1:
        songs = [song1]
    else:
        x = True
        """html_content = urllib.request.urlopen(song1)
        html_content = html_content.read().decode()"""
        r = requests.get(song1)
        html_content = r.text
        pattern = "href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})"
        songs = re.findall(pattern,html_content)
        print(f"Before: {songs}")

        songs = list(dict.fromkeys(songs))
        print(f"after: {songs}")
            #songs.append(f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={code}")

    for search in songs:
        s = search if not x else f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={search}"
        try:

            source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, s, loop=self.bot.loop)
        except YTDLError as e:
            await ctx.send('An error occurred while processing this request: {}'.format(str(e)))
        else:
            song = Song(source)

            await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song)
            if not x:
                await ctx.send('Enqueued {}'.format(str(source)))
    if x:
        await ctx.send(f"Succesfully queued the playlist `{song1}`")
```

Here what is in the console

Command that I run I discord:

```
pplay https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2n_fVXKImKlfv3PlcHZTzLk3CoGUV9Hm
```

output when it works:

```
Before: ['gEbRqpFkTBk', 'gEbRqpFkTBk', 'gEbRqpFkTBk', 'gEbRqpFkTBk', '4ZvnbsfXRk0', '4ZvnbsfXRk0', 'besNDPvEwQw', 'besNDPvEwQw', 'QglaLzo_aPk', 'QglaLzo_aPk', 'YJTae5ScvQA', 'YJTae5ScvQA', '9Va88Kt0NN0', '9Va88Kt0NN0']
after: ['gEbRqpFkTBk', '4ZvnbsfXRk0', 'besNDPvEwQw', 'QglaLzo_aPk', 'YJTae5ScvQA', '9Va88Kt0NN0']
```

output most of the time:

```
Before: []
after: []
```

It doesn't give any error.

Comment: I've had problems with `youtube_dl` before. Maybe try updating

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extract_info` method from youtube-dl :

```py
video_list = []

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
    playlist = ydl.extract_info(url='playlist url', download=False)['entries']

for video in playlist:
    video_list.append(video['webpage_url'])
```

`video_list` will contain every URLs from your playlist's videos.

Comment: Yo. for some reason it doesn't work the error is ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed> (caused by URLError(gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))) what should i do

Comment: Could you give me the playlist url ? I used the url you gave in your post, it works perfectly. Have you replaced 'playlist url' with a proper playlist url ?

Comment: i figured the error. But now it's very slow, it loads the playlist really slow.
[link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2n_fVXKImKlfv3PlcHZTzLk3CoGUV9Hm)

Comment: I said that it was the easiest way, not the fastest one ^^